# Pass the field name of struct to access inside a function

Tags: c, struct, linked-list

I have a linked list and I made a function to fetch a node. But I want to use it both to search by first or last name.

```
typedef struct people {
   char name[60],
        lastname[60];
   struct people *next;
} people;

people *search(const char *key, people *list, FIELD) {
    while (list && strcmp(key, list->FIELD) != 0) {
        list = list->next;
    }
    return list;
}
```

Example:

```
people *aux;
aux = search("John", list_of_people, "name");
```

Or:

```
aux = search("Smith", list_of_people, "lastname");
```

There is a clear and efficient way to solve this problem without repeating code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `offsetof(<stddef.h>)` macro.

E.g:

```
people *search(const char *key, people *list, size_t FIELD) {// FIELD is field offset,
    while (list && strcmp(key, (char*)list + FIELD) != 0) {
        list = list->next;
    }
    return list;
}
```

call

```
aux = search("John", list_of_people, offsetof(people, name));
aux = search("Smith", list_of_people, offsetof(people, lastname));
```

Comment: I really liked this solution. Simple and efficient.

Answer (score 2):

With just two fields, this seems like the obvious way:

```
people *search(const char *key, people *list, bool first) {
    while (list && strcmp(key, first ? list->name : list->lastname) != 0) {
        list = list->next;
    }
    return list;
}
```

For a more general case, something like this would work:

```
struct mystruct {
    char field1[60];
    char field2[60];
    char field3[60];
    char field4[60];
    char field5[60];
    struct mystruct * next;
}

char * get_field(struct mystruct * list, size_t field) {
    char * fields[] = { list->field1, list->field2, list->field3,
                        list->field4, list->field5 };
    return fields[field];
}

people *search(const char *key, people *list, bool first) {
    while (list && strcmp(key, get_field(list, 3)) != 0) {
        list = list->next;
    }
    return list;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using an `enum` to do the different searches.

```
enum {SEARCH_BY_FIRSTNAME, SEARCH_BY_LASTNAME};

char* getSeachName(people* list, int searchBy)
{
   return ( searchBy == SEARCH_BY_FIRSTNAME ? list->name : list->lastname );
}

people *search(const char *key, people *list, int searchBy) {
    while (list && strcmp(key, getSearchName(list, searchBy)) != 0) {
        list = list->next;
    }
    return list;
}

// Search by first name.
people *aux;
aux = search("John", list_of_people, SEARCH_BY_FIRSTNAME);

// Search by last name.
aux = search("Smith", list_of_people, SEARCH_BY_LASTNAME);
```

Comment: I prefer your `enum` solution, but why is the absolutely unnecessary extra function and it's call the `getName()`?

Comment: @PeterVaro The extra function is not absolutely necessary. I just think in terms functions most of the time. You can use `( searchBy == SEARCH_BY_FIRSTNAME ? list->name : list->lastname )` instead of `getName(list, searchBy)`. Perhaps `getSearchName` would be more appropriate in this case.

Comment: as a matter of fact in C integer `0` is `false`, while all the other numbers are true, and since you are using enums, you could do: `searchBy ? list->lastname :  list->name` and that's all

Comment: @PeterVaro, I think `( searchBy == SEARCH_BY_FIRSTNAME ? list->name : list->lastname )` is more readable than `(searchBy? list->name : list->lastname)`. Unless it's a performance issue, all of us should prefer more readable code.

Comment: then change the variable name! `last_name ?  list->lastname : list->name`

Comment: @PeterVaro, That would be a good change. It will also work if `name` could be changed to `firstname` in `struct people`.

Comment: exactly, but that wasn't your call, it was the OPs, but I agree with you